# slick-slider: использовать блоки как dots

Tags: javascript

Нужно каким-либо образом привязать блоки к кнопкам. При клике на блок slick-slider должен переключать слайд.

http://codepen.io/iddqdoom/pen/ZpZOZO

```js
$('.single-item').slick();
```

```css
.b-main__block {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
}
.single-item {
  text-align: center;
}
.b-slider-nav__item {
  margin: 10px;
  font: normal 3em/2 Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}
.b-footer {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-slider-nav">
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-nav__item">1</div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-nav__item">2</div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-nav__item">3</div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-nav__item">4</div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-nav__item">5</div>
</div>
<div class="single-item">
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-for__item">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia
      voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
      modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit,
      qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti,
      quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero
      tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus
      saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-for__item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-for__item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-for__item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-main__block b-slider-for__item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="b-footer">footer</footer>
```

Comment: как например `$('.single-item').slick({
  dots: true,
  customPaging : function(slider, i) {    
       return '<div class="b-main__block b-slider-nav__item">'+(i+1)+'</div>';
  }        
});` + стили править

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего случая подойдет такой вариант:

```
$('.b-slider-nav__item').click(function() {
  $('.single-item').slickGoTo($(this).index());
});
```

Метод `slickGoTo` переключает на слайд с указанным номером в качестве аргумента.
Плюсом указанного решения является то, что никакие стили править не надо.

Пример на [codepen](http://codepen.io/VenZell/pen/ALxVVO), поскольку в здешнем сниппете у меня ошибка загрузка jQuery.

---

Для новой версии Slick (c 1.6.0, может раньше) нужно использовать такой синтаксис:

```
$('.b-slider-nav__item').click(function() {
  $('.single-item').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).index());
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает прекрасно на 1.3.7! Заметил особенность - ваш пример не работает с slick 1.6.0. Существует фикс?

Comment: @НикитаКосарев, дело не в фиксе, а смене синтаксиса в новых версиях Slick. Я обновил ответ